# Duplicated characters in dict

Tags: python, combinations

I did this code:

```
import itertools
black = "Ellie"
s = "E111e"
messagelist = list(s)
a = s.count("1")
dicta = {}
for x in messagelist:
    if not x == "1":
        dicta[x] = messagelist.index(x)
        print(dicta)
listo = ['l', 'i', 'j',]
result = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(listo, a)
lista2 = []
for each in result:
    a =str(each).replace("(", "")
    a = a.replace(")", "")
    a = a.replace(",", "")
    a = a.replace("'", "")
    a = a.replace(" ", "")
    lista2.append(a)
lista3 = []
for x in lista2:
        listexa = list(x)
        for item in dicta:
            listexa.insert(dicta[item], item)
        listexa = "".join(listexa)
        lista3.append(listexa)
print(lista3)
if black in lista3:
    print("DELETE")
else:
    print("IT'S OKAY")
```

```
black = blacklisted word
```

```
s = user writing it with numbers
```

The problem is with words that contains more than one egual character like "finishing" that has 2 "n" characters, so in the dict, only 1 "n" will be added how can I solve this?

Comment: Instead of putting a single index in the dict for every letter that occures you could try using a list of indices and append the current index to the end.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick for you:

(I also tweaked the `for` loop, where you were iterating over combinations - just to keep it pythonish ;) )

```py
import itertools

def repl(txt, pat):
    if(len(pat)==0):
        return txt
    return repl(txt.replace("1", pat[0], 1), pat[1:])

black = "Ellie"
s = "E111e"
messagelist = list(s)
a = s.count("1")
dicta = {}

listo = ['l', 'i', 'j',]
result = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(listo, a)
lista2 = []
for each in result:
    lista2.append("".join(each))
lista3 = []
for x in lista2:
        listexa = repl(s, x)
        lista3.append(listexa)
print(lista3)
if black in lista3:
    print("DELETE")
else:
    print("IT'S OKAY")
```

Consider function `repl` - the most important improvement. It essentially leverages the fact that `python` `str.replace()` can also take 3rd argument, which in essence defines number of replacements to be done - just to replace `1` one at a time.